# Meteor on android device can't get GPS position

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, ngcordova

I have a mobile application done in Meteor + ionic and I'm trying to get the user GPS location using this simple code:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function ( result ) {
    console.log( result );
    Session.set( 'pos', result );
}, function ( err ) {
    console.log( err );
});
```

All I get is a warning saying that `getCurrentPosition` deprecated on insecure locations.

Why is my app seen as an insecure location since I'm running it with `meteor run android-device` which basically installs it on my phone then runs it like any other app?

If I open up the chrome inspector and control the app's browser I can switch the url from `http://meteor.local` to `https://meteor.local` making it a "secure location" but all I get is a timeout error when `getCurrentPosition`  is fired.

So...how does one get the user's position inside a meteor mobile application?

Comment: You can add following native geolocation plugin using tarball url: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-integration#adding-cordova-specific-javascript-code-to-your-application) you need to use the cordova geolocation plugin. I believe this is because the webview used by cordova may not have all the features of chrome on your mobile -- which is a natural but wrong assumption.

According to the [geolocation plugin readme](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/blob/master/packages/mdg:geolocation/README.md) you need to add the plugin:

```
meteor add mdg:geolocation.
```

and then you can use:

```
Geolocation.currentLocation()
```

There might be a way to do this all with `navigator.geolocation`, but if you use the native functionality provided via the plugin then you won't need to worry much about security consideration in browsers. It will also ensure that things will work on older devices that may use a version of the webview that doesn't yet implement the geo API.

Comment: I have it installed. And if you look at it's source code it uses the same code from navigator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using the navigator.geolocation. It seems like the error function will never be fired because the timeout default value is actually infinity. To solve it is to actually set a minimum timeout value.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,error,{timeout:5000});
```